# What's wrong with the write method of the MRSW register class?

Tags: java, multithreading

In the book '[The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](https://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/134637/Herlihy,_Shavit_-_The_art_of_multiprocessor_programming.pdf)' you find the AtomicMRSWRegister Java class on page 84. 
In [figure 4.13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rALdP.png) of this book it is illustrated that the writer writes diagonally as reflected on line 32 of Figure 4.12: `a_table[i][i] = value;`.

But in the [errata](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~multi/errata.pdf) of this book they say it should be `a_table [ 0 ][ i ] = value;` instead, in which case it does not write diagonally. Which would contradict the diagional writting in [figure 4.13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rALdP.png).

So what is going on?

```java
public class AtomicMRSWRegister<T> implements Register<T> {
    ThreadLocal<Long> lastStamp;
    private StampedValue<T>[][] a_table; // each entry is SRSW atomic

    public AtomicMRSWRegister(T init, int readers) {
        lastStamp = new ThreadLocal<Long>() {
            protected Long initialValue() { return 0; };
        };

        a_table = (StampedValue<T>[][]) new StampedValue[readers][readers];
        StampedValue<T> value = new StampedValue<T>(init);

        for (int i = 0; i < readers; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < readers; j++) {
                a_table[i][j] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public T read() {
        int me = ThreadID.get();
        StampedValue<T> value = a_table[me][me];

        for (int i = 0; i < a_table.length; i++) {
            value = StampedValue.max(value, a_table[i][me]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a_table.length; i++) {
            a_table[me][i] = value;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public void write(T v) {
        long stamp = lastStamp.get() + 1;
        lastStamp.set(stamp);
        StampedValue<T> value = new StampedValue<T>(stamp, v);

        for (int i = 0; i < a_table.length; i++) {
            a_table[i][i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Figure 4.12 The AtomicMRSWRegister class: an atomic MRSW register constructed from
atomic SRSW registers.